# How to preserve the input shape inserting data with rmoutliers() in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, outliers

I'd like to remove outliers with `rmoutliers()` in MATLAB preserving the shape of the input array. Is there a way to use `rmoutliers()`, which inserts e.g. interpolated values into the "holes" it creates?

If not, can anybody provide an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is just a method called `filloutliers()`. Leaving this here in case anybody faces similar problem.